# Time comparison of add method for: ArrayList, LinkedList, ArrayList (initialized with some value)

Tags: java, performance, list, arraylist, linked-list

I wish to know more about data structure and about their implementations (in JAVA language). Today I wrote a test to compare (time comparison) different implementations of the ADT List. Specifically I compared add method, here's my test:

```
@Test
public void testTime() {
    long i = 10000000;
    long INITIALIZED_VALUE=5000000;
    List<Integer> arrayBasedList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    List<Integer> linkedBasedList = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    List<Integer> arrayBasedInitialedSizeList = new ArrayList<Integer> (INITIALIZED_VALUE);

    long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for (int index = 0; index <= i; index++) {
        arrayBasedList.add(index);
    }
    long t1End = System.currentTimeMillis() - t1;

    long t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();

    for (int index = 0; index <= i; index++) {
        linkedBasedList.add(index);
    }
    long t2End = System.currentTimeMillis() - t2;

    long t3 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for (int index = 0; index <= i; index++) {
        arrayBasedInitialedSizeList.add(index);
    }
    long t3End = System.currentTimeMillis() - t3;

    System.out.println("ArrayBased: " + t1End);
    System.out.println("LinkedList:" + t2End);
    System.out.println("ArrayBasedInitializedSize: " + t3End);

    System.out.println("End");
}
```

And I obtained this result:

> ArrayBased: 5681 LinkedList:12830 ArrayBasedInitializedSize: 858

Why LinkedList is slower than ArrayList implementation? I thought that add method, for LinkedList implementation, was faster than add method for Array implementation.

Anyone can explain me why array is faster than linkedlist for the add method?

Thanks

Alessio

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two things here.

The first is that your timings are unreliable as you haven't "warmed up" the code before each run. Java optimizes and compiles code as it is run so the first few times through it are much slower than later runs. You should run through your test loops a few hundred times, throw those results away and then do the timings.

To answer the question though:

`LinkedList` is constant time no matter how long the list is but on each add it has to do a lot more work. It needs to create the wrapper object, insert it into the list, update references, etc.

On the other hand `ArrayList` just sets a value into the array and then increments the size counter. Only if it needs to re-allocate the array does it then have to do a lot of work.

Do the test adding new objects at the start and compare the results though and you will see things swing more back in the favor of linked lists as now `ArrayList` needs to shuffle up all the values every time.

The cost to reallocate the arrays is also illustrated with your third test, by knowing the size in advance the ArrayList becomes even more efficient.

Big O notation is helpful when discussing algorithms, but you need to understand what it actually means or it can be very misleading. It's talking about the Order of the operation, not how long it actually takes. `ArrayList` and `LinkedList` are both O(1) for most append insertions, `ArrayList` insertion is O(n) if it needs to reallocate.

All O(1) says is that it still takes the same amount of time no matter how many objects are in the list. Add something to the end of a 10 item list, 100 item list, 10000 item list it still takes the same time.

LinkedList though takes more time than ArrayList does - even though they still have the same O(1) order.

In fact the speed difference is such that even if you look at adding to the start of the list where LinkedList is O(1) and ArrayList is O(n) ArrayList is still faster for small lists!

To give some idea (this is just an example, don't try and take exact timings out of this!) then if the time taken to add for a LinkedList is L and the time for an ArrayList is A then the total time to do an add at the end is L*1, A*1. To add at the start is L*1, A*N.

So if L/A < N then its actually faster to use an ArrayList even though just looking at the O characteristics you might think you are better using the LinkedList.

(Linked list is also O(n) if you need random access reads, which can be a big factor too).

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for your answer. I repeat the test as you suggested.
How can we express, through Big O notation in the worse case, time for add method in Array implementation?

Comment: Soryy, I mean worst case.

Comment: Great Tim, I understand what you're saying and I explained badly my thought, that was very similar to yours. But you give a great explanation.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In short: add operation on ArrayList is faster than on LinkedList because it involves (read, write, update) less memory locations:

- ArrayList: update `int size` field, read `Object[] elements` field, read `elements.length`, write to `elements` at index.
- LinkedList: update `int size` field, update `Entry tail` field, allocate new `Entry`, write    to the new entry's `prev` and `element` fields, write `tail.next` field.

More precise timings:

```
@GenerateMicroBenchmark
public int arrayList_add() {
    List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>(1000);
    Object x = new Object();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        list.add(x);
    }
    return list.size();
}

@GenerateMicroBenchmark
public int linkedList_add() {
    List<Object> list = new LinkedList<>();
    Object x = new Object();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        list.add(x);
    }
    return list.size();
```

Results:

```
Benchmark             Mean   Mean error    Units
arrayList_add        5,234        0,019  usec/op
linkedList_add       6,417        0,032  usec/op
```

Answer (score 0):

I was surprised by your results and tried to run your code by myself. Here is my output:

```
ArrayBased: 5589
LinkedList:1219
ArrayBasedInitializedSize: 789
End
```

As I think, LinkedList's add method should work just a little bit slower than ArrayList (both O(1), but with different constant). They both create new Integer objects and ArrayList just puts them in the array, while LinkedList creates links.

The difference between ArrayBased and ArrayBasedInitializedSize is obvious: array reallocation and elements copying take too much time.

Comment: Hi sas4eka,

time for Array implementation with a specific value in initializazion doesn't surprise myself. I reported the value because it was present inside my test. Add for Array based impl is O(1)? Are you talking about best case?

Comment: Sorry for the inaccuracy. In this case I was talking about ArrayList add(Integer i) method, which adds an element in the end and takes O(1) time. The  method add(int index, Integer i), which puts an element in the middle of the ArrayList take O(n) time in the worst case.

Comment: I was talking about the for loop, what is its running time in your opinion?